# Durandal 2.0.1, Tryactivate getting called again and again

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

I am using Durandal 2.0.1 for my application.

I am using below html code to compose view and viewmodel.

```
<div id="graphid" data-bind="compose: { model: 'templates/graphControl', view: 'templates/graphControl' }, visible: showGraph"></div>
```

The problem which I am facing is that, whenever I am trying to toggle the **visibility** of the above div, **tryactivate** is getting called again and again. Is it the expected behaviour or is there something I am doing wrong.
Can anyone tell/explain why is this happening, if it is a known behaviour.

Can anyone just explain why is this happening.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're gonna need to post more code. If at all possible, a jsfiddle that reproduces your problem would be the most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue similar to this last night. Based on your code, give the following a try

```
        <!--ko visible: showGraph-->
            <!--ko compose: { model: 'templates/graphControl', view: 'templates/graphControl' }--><!--/ko-->
        <!--/ko-->
```

Comment: Even I have solved in somewhat similar manner.
I have solved this issue by by toggling the visibility of the above div(div above <div id="graphid" ....></div>)

I want to know why is this happening?? when we are using visible in the same div.

Comment: Well im not sure for the exact reason but if you check the documentation, it dosent mention visible as a valid property for the compose binding.